# link no se abre en html

Tags: html, extensión-google-chrome

Estoy desarrollando una extensión de Chrome en la cual petendo abrir un enlace. Para ello, uso la siguiente línea:

```
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" onclick="window.open(href)">Y</a>
```

No sé mucho de este lenguaje y no sé por qué no funciona, puesto que en los tutoriales que he visto se hacía así. He probado a poner otros enlaces y el resultado ha sido el mismo.

Comment: Copia el código completo. Cambia a onclick="window.open(href)"

Comment: `<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a>` y listo. Ver: **[El elemento `<a>`Anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a)**

Comment: Si no me equivoco con esto te abre el link en una página nueva, pruébalo y comentas <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">Y</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El elemento `anchor` de HTML, representando por la etiqueta `<a>` admite los siguientes atributos:

- `href`
- `hreflang`
- `referrerpolicy`
- `rel`
- `target`
- `type`
- `download` (a partir de HTML5)

Como dato curioso, el atributo `title`, que es muy usado, no aparece en la actual documentación.

Hay otros atributos ya obsoletos como: `charset`

Para ver el uso de cada una de estos atributos puedes consultar [la documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a), la cual existe en castellano.

Para crear un enlace simplemente puedes hacer:

`<a href="https://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a>`

Y dentro de la `<a>` de apertura puedes colocar una o más de las etiquetas mencionadas más arriba.

Ejemplo:

```html
<p>Sin nada:</p>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a><br />
<p>Con título, usando la etiqueta  <code>title</code> . Deja un  momento el puntero sobre el enlace:</p>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" title="Ir a Yo tuve :)">YouTube</a>
<p>Abrir enlace en otra página, usando la etiqueta  <code>target</code>:</p>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" title="Ir a Youtube :)" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
```

Con respecto a `onclick` [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a) dice lo siguiente:

> Se abusa frecuntemente de las etiquetas de ancla (anchor tags) con el
>   uso de los eventos **`onclick`** para crear pseudo-botones ajustando `href`
>   a "`#`" o "`javascript:void(0)`" para prevenir la recarga de la página.
>   Estos valores provocan comportamientos inesperados con los enlaces de
>   copiado/dibujado, la apertura de enlaces en nuevas pestañas/ventanas,
>   el guardado de enlaces (bookmarking), y cuando JavaScript está aún
>   descargando, esto arroja errores, o es deshabilitado. Esto tambíen
>   lleva a semánticas (semantics) incorrectas para tecnologías de
>   asistencia (p.ej., lectores de pantalla). En estos casos, se
>   recomienda utilizar un `<button>` en su lugar. En general, sólo se debe
>   utilizar una ancla (anchor) para navegación utilizando una URL
>   adecuada.

Cabe decir también que la etiqueta `<a>` no se usa sólo para enlaces a páginas web externas mediante el protocolo `http`, sino también para enlaces en la misma página usando `#seccion`, así como enlaces a direcciones `ftp`, a direcciones de `email`, a imágenes, a números de teléfono. Todo ello está detallado en la documentación (enlace de más arriba).

Answer (score 1):

Con esto simplemente:

```
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Texto del enlace</a><p>
```

Ya te abriría la página de youtube, para este caso.

Si lo que quieres es abrirlo en una ventana nueva, sería este otro caso:

```
<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Texto del enlace</a></p>
```

El atributo `onclick` solo es por si lo que quieres es añadirle otro tipo de funcionalidades, a través de ajax, javascript,..